# Несколько вопросов по Edittext

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

Возникло несколько вопросов в процессе создания мини-браузера.
У меня есть `EditText`, который служит адресной строкой для открытия страниц в `WebView`. Настало время его усовершенствовать и вот что мне для этого нужно:

1. Убрать обязательный ввод http:// перед доменом, чтобы можно было сразу вводить, к примеру, google.com. Как такое можно реализовать?
2. "Научить" `EditText` получать адрес текущей открытой страницы в `WebView, а то, к примеру, если я через строчку открыла google.com, а потом перешла на stackoverflow.com, то в строке останется google.com. Опять же, как такое возможно реализовать?
3. И последнее, что меня интересует - это добавление поиска Google в строку, но при этом чтобы `EditText` понимал, когда вводится запрос для поиска, а когда готовый веб-адрес.

   Извиняюсь, если я поставила для вас слишком сложные вопросы.

   Большое спасибо вам заранее!

Comment: Видимо, ссылку на урок вы не вставили)

Comment: Извиняюсь) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: Вы всегда можете самостоятельно редактировать свой вопрос, добавляя нужную для его решения информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. А можно добавить http:// когда это нужно.

   ```
   String url = EditText.GetText();
   if (url.StartsWith('http://', 0) {
     url = 'http://' + url;
   }
   browser.loadUrl(url);
   ```
2. Получить текущий урл - у объекта есть готовый метод `getUrl()`. А вот куда именно его добавить - это уже отдельная история.
3. А вот тут есть сложность. Не всегда даже человеку понятно, это будет урл или текст. В целом, Вам нужно придумать подобную функцию, а потом написать что то вида

   ```
   if (IsItText(text)) {
     browser.loadUrl('http://google.com?q=' + text);
   } else {
     browser.loadUrl(text);
   }
   ```